# jQuery: What's the proper way to use (document).ready(); in a .click() and .load() combination?

Tags: jquery, leaflet, document-ready

I'm trying to create a menu for a mobile app which trades the contents of my `#content` - DIV to new content from a .HTML - file.

I'm using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu li').click(function(){
        $('#content').load(this.id + '.html #content *');               
    });
});
```

This works, except for one HTML-File:

```
<div id="content">  
    <div id="map"></div> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/default.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>              
    <script src="assets/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</div>
```

I'm trying to load a map which is generated by the Leaflet-API, but there's only the empty DIV-Container (`#map`) parsed by every browser.

I think the problem might be that my `map.js` isn't fired after the DOM is built. 
Tried to fix this with `$(document).ready()` but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Would be great, cheers!

Comment: Do you load jQuery in that HTML file?

Comment: No i didn't. Added a link to jQuery and my other JS file now, but nothing changed.

Comment: You need to load jQuery before `map.js`, did you?

Comment: Does the file have `<ol id="menu">`?

Comment: Yes, everything is loaded before `map.js`

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: There is a DIV with `id="menu"` in the outer HTML file. Only the `#content` DIV should be changed here, what works for every other HTML file.

Comment: Unfortunately no errors :(

Comment: What's different between this file and one of the files that works? If you put an alert in the click handler, does it fire?

Comment: The difference is, that i'm trying to load Leaflet-generated code into my `#map` - DIV in order to create the map. Every other file is simple HTML. So my guess was i messed up the `document.ready()` placement.

Comment: So the code in `this.id + ".html"` contains Javascript that calls leaflet functions? If not, I'm not sure I understand how leaflet is related to what you're doing.

Comment: In this case `this.id + ".html"` results in `interactivemap.html`, which is the code i've copied above. There's nothing else in it except of these 7 lines. Do you think the way I used `.ready()` is fine in this case? Sorry if it's confusing, I'm confused as well :)

Comment: In your map.js do you use $(document).ready() to start your map ? I think in this case you should not do

Comment: No i don't. I think the `map.js` file is fine, it only contains basic leaflet stuff at the moment.

Comment: Just a guess. Did you set a height to your map div ?

Comment: Yes and it's not too big as well... the map itself and it's script works, tested it on a different page. It only doesn't work if i try to open it through my menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the load jquery docs you can read

Script Execution

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.

And you are calling load with a selector expression...

I would do in other way.

1. Modify your map.js to contain a function (i.e mapInit ) that executes your map stuff.
2. Put all this scrips tag in head of the general html document.
3. Call load with a callback to your map function

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#menu li').click(function(){
       $('#content').load(this.id + '.html #content *',mapInit());               
     });
   });
   ```